# MBP M1 Pro usb accessories disabled prompt when connecting a display using USB-C

Tags: display, usb, battery, sleep-wake, charging

I have the MacBook Pro (14-inch, 2021) with M1 Pro and connecting it to the ProArt Display PA329CV.

When I'm normally working on my laptop the display works fine. However if the Mac goes to sleep and then I wake it up, I see a notification saying "usb accessories disabled". The odd thing is that the display still works with the MBP, and the battery indicator says fully charged and connected to the power adaptor.

I'm confused as to what the issue is, or whether it's a bug with Mac OS. The ProArt Display PA329CV can connect to the Mac via USB-C with 90W Power Delivery.

If I try to use the USB-C connector simply for the display, and use the mag-safe charger to power the MBP then the monitor doesn't work at all.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. I also tried the firmware update and it gets worse. ASUS has acknowledge the issue for their 27 inch variant of the ProArt 9CV series, but nothing has been done for 32 inch yet.

Definitely do not update the firmware that got released in January 2022, the monitor freezes everytime my M1 Pro/Max macbook goes to sleep, and I have to power it off and on for 5 seconds to revive it. Terrible.

Before the update I only got the annoying message of USB device using too much power, now it is so much more annoying that before, unusable sometimes